# How to customize Sitecore Media Library

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How can I modify the Sitecore media library? I need to customize it to integrate with sharepoint and require to implement further functionality to what the Sitecore Sharepoint Connector currently does. I'm looking at how to get started customizing the media library as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore has recently released a new SharePoint integration module called [SharePoint Integration Framework](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/SPIF.aspx). Take a look whether it covers your requirements towards media library customization - it should be more flexible, more extensible and richer in features than the [well-known SharePoint Connector module](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/SharePoint%20Connector.aspx).

Comment: Hi Yan, my question is more on how do I get started in modifying the Media Library. As a start I'd like to just begin modifying the UI and perhaps displaying files in the sitecore media library which reside in sharepoint. The Connector does this, however it doesn't let you upload images to sharepoint from within the media library which is our next requirement.

Comment: That's why I suggested trying another SP integration module (see the link above), it can fit your requirements better. BTW, it would be great if you are more specific about what is meant by "customize Media library" and "modify the UI"...